# Error while installing ns 2.35 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ns2

I receive the following error while installing ns 2.35 (sudo ./install) in ubuntu.

config.status: creating Makefile

rm -f libotcl.a otcl.o

gcc -V 4.5 -c -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -DUSE_SHM -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I. -I/home/arya/ns-allinone-
2.35/include -I/home/arya/ns-allinone-2.35/include -I/home/arya/ns-allinone-
2.35/include -I/include  otcl.c

gcc: error: 4.5: No such file or directory

gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-V’

make: *** [libotcl.a] Error 1

otcl-1.14 make failed! Exiting ...

I changed the Makefile.in in /ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14

CC = @CC@ -V 4.6.3

where -V 4.6.3 represents the gcc version.

How to remove this error. Could not find any related help in google.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to missing of the configure file in the octl folder
the best way is download again the ns package and try to install

install g++ 4.9

```
$ sudo apt install g++-4.9
```

Run the installaer from

```
export CC=gcc-4.9 CXX=g++-4.9 && ./install
```